# what does module exports = mongoose model do in NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am coming sort of front-end React world and have mostly used statements like import and exports.

I know there are numerous article highlighting **How** we can use import and export in nodeJS and I also know that this might not have anything to do with import and export.

Either way, I was starting to learn Backend (NodeJs) along with mongoDB.

I am using express framework and package name mongoose.

Inside, models, we were creating a schema as simple as this

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const bookSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    genre: String, 
    authorID: String
})


module.exports = mongoose.model("Books", bookSchema)
```

While I understand what we are doing above, creating a schema above and exporting, I am unable to comprehend the export statement

```
module.exports = mongoose.model("Books", bookSchema)
```

Like, I understand it does export mongoose schema but what does `mongoose.model` do/mean? like behind the scenes?

Comment: It probably means that we are making a model inside our `mongoose Database` which will be named books and would have schema like that of `bookSchema` you are creating.

Comment: It will create `books` collection in your database and documents inside that collection will have fields from `bookSchema` when you save first document.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html)

> Models are fancy constructors compiled from Schema definitions. An
>   instance of a model is called a document. Models are responsible for
>   creating and reading documents from the underlying MongoDB database.

---

**Schema** are the description of the data. **Model** kind of represent your collection. You can have multiple **Model** having the same **Schema**. To create new documents, or to get documents from database, you need to use **Model**.

---

To use the model as you described it :

**a.js**

```
// ...

module.exports = mongoose.model('Books', bookSchema)
```

**b.js**

```
import Books from 'a.js';

// We create a new document and then save it in database    
const book = new Books({
  name: 'Harry potter',
  genre: 'drama',
  authorID: 'JK',
});

// Save is asynchronous and can fail
await book.save();
```